# Mass Delete Tax Rate

Tags: tax

Is there a way to mass delete tax rates from Magento backend?

The Magento documentation shows that in Magento GO, each tax rate has a checkbox that you can use to mass delete rates. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/deleting-tax-rates. This checkbox doesn't appear next to tax rates on my Magento Community edition.

When I import new tax rates, they don't overrwite the current tax rates, they create new ones. This has resulted in thousands of tax rates. I want to clear them all out and start from scratch.

Is there a way to edit the database to clean out the tax rate information?

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 tables with all rates.

Im not sure what happens with old orders, and what you wanna do with that.

but can you can truncate this tables, and see if that fix your problem.

```
tax_calculation     
tax_calculation_rate
tax_calculation_rate_title
tax_calculation_rule
tax_class
```

Comment: I don't exactly know how to use this information to accomplish what I'm after, but I'll play around some more and report back. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the following method, but it does require some digging and know what you are doing. It will put the "select all" option to select the whole page instead of checking them one by one.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/

If you need tax rate tables, check out https://www.woosalestax.com. They have formatted tax rate table for all the U.S. states. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following script.

```
function deleteTaxRate() {

try {

    foreach (Mage::getModel('tax/calculation_rate')->getcollection() as $rate) {
        echo 'Tax Rate Deleted : '.$rate->getId();
        $rate->delete();
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Delete tax rate failed '.PHP_EOL;
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

}